# How to remove hover class on keydown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

could you please tell me how to remove hover class on keydown .I do the following steps

1) Hover the second item .It apply the hover class on second item "b"

Now if user press the keydown event code 40 .It remove the hover class from element ? how I can remove hover class from keydown event ?

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qp6ex1jh/2/)

```
 $(function() {
     $('#main-menu').on({
         mouseenter: function() {
             console.log("mouse over")
         },
         mouseleave: function() {
             console.log("mouse leave")
         }
     });



 })

 $(document).on('keyup', function(event) {

     if (event.which == 40) { // 40 is Array key down event code
         console.log('remove focus or hover from selected item ');

     }
 })
```

Comment: For anyone who doesn't know the keycodes on top of it's head.. 40 is for `Arrow key down`.

Comment: What happens if the user never hovers any of your elements?

Comment: Just FYI, keydown != keyup...

Comment: were you looking for this? https://jsfiddle.net/qp6ex1jh/4/ 
note that just by hovering on list item will not get the focus to it you need to click in order for keydown to work :)

Comment: Not working fiddle..sorry Actually It is not removing the background color

Comment: after keydown ..Steps first hover the b or second element.and use keydown to remove the hower class

Comment: Do you want to unbind your fonctions on focus or hover ? If so, just do `$('#main-menu').off("mouseenteer").off("mouseleave");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> could you please tell me how to remove hover class on keydown

hover is not a class, you need to make one and add/remove the same on mousenter and mouseleave.

try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/qp6ex1jh/7/)

```
$('#main-menu').on("mouseenter", "li", function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "hover" ); 
});
$('#main-menu').on("mouseleave", "li", function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "hover" ); 
});

$(document).ready( function(){

    $( "li" ).first().focus();

    $(document).keydown(function () {
        console.log(event.which);
        if(event.which==40)
        {
            console.log('remove focus or hover from selected item ');
            $( "li.hover" ).removeClass( "hover" ).next().addClass( "hover" );
        }
    });

} );
```